# Leaderboard ranking using django

Tags: django

I have a web-site which have scores per each user.

I would like to provide a leader-board and to be able to tell each user (on his profile page for example) his place in the leader board.

I suspect that doing that may have a serious performance issue. current solution for me is to order by points and just get the user from its current location. however, if I'll have to do it per user it will be deadly to my DB.

any better approches ?

Comment: You can have a cron job/celery task that periodically updates the ranking, where ranking is a database field per user. Basically, the cron job/ celery task computes the ranking on a periodical fashion

Comment: problem here is that sometimes the leaderboard will be incorrect..

Comment: If you can avoid real time at first and cache your results for a period of time it's going to be fine unless you have hundreds of visitors.. You can always start short polling first, task queue with celery as karthikr suggested.. Lots of options, you ought to try things first.

Comment: celery tasks have minimal delay. Also, unless you are tracking realtime rankings, i dont think couple of seconds is a huge issue. Example stackexchange - they have a slight lag in updating the user ranks, but not showing the user reputation points. (Choice of design)

Comment: Yes , I understand. However assuming I have millions of users, updating the ranking each couple of minutes can be expensive. I thought about doing some kind of optimization, but its really relates to the way I rank and provide points on my site. Thanks for your help !

Comment: I've just started working on a similar thing and was wondering if an [extra manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) couldn't take care of this?